# Проблема с декодом

Tags: code-analyst

```
"60de77b2-620b-49d8-af29-9c78cc67a0b1":  {
                "name": "\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",
                "description": "",
                "access": "1",
                "default": "",
                "repeatable": "0",
                "select_names": "\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",
                "items": "\u0410\u043b\u0430\u043d\u044c\u044f\r\n-\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440\r\n-\u041c\u0430\u0445\u043c\u0443\u0442\u043b\u0430\u0440\r\n-\u0422\u043e\u0441\u043c\u0443\u0440\r\n-\u041e\u0431\u0430\r\n-\u0414\u0435\u043c\u0438\u0440\u0442\u0430\u0448\r\n-\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0430\u043a\u043b\u044b\r\n-\u0422\u0443\u0440\u043a\u043b\u0435\u0440\r\n-\u0414\u0436\u0438\u043a\u0447\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\r\n-\u041a\u0430\u0440\u0433\u0438\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043a\r\n-\u0410\u0432\u0441\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0430\u0440\r\n-\u041a\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\r\n-\u041a\u043b\u0435\u043e\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0440\u0430\r\n-\u0413\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043f\u0430\u0448\u0430\r\n\u0410\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438\u044f\r\n-\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043a\r\n-\u0421\u0438\u0434\u0435\r\n-\u0410\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438\u044f\r\n-\u041a\u0435\u043c\u0435\u0440\r\n-\u041a\u043e\u043d\u044c\u044f\u043b\u0442\u044b\r\n-\u041a\u0443\u043d\u0434\u0443\r\n-\u0425\u0443\u0440\u043c\u0430\r\n\u041a\u0430\u0448\r\n\u0424\u0435\u0442\u0445\u0438\u0435\r\n\u0411\u043e\u0434\u0440\u0443\u043c\r\n-\u0411\u043e\u0434\u0440\u0443\u043c\r\n-\u042f\u043b\u044b\u043a\u0430\u0432\u0430\u043a\r\n-\u0422\u044e\u0440\u043a\u0431\u044e\u043a\u044e\r\n-\u0413\u044e\u043d\u0434\u043e\u0430\u043d\r\n-\u0413\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043a\r\n",
"type": "jbselectcascade"
},
```

Точно знаю что тут закодирован русский тескт, можно как-то раскодировать?

Comment: Похоже, там есть решение :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835317/unicode-value-uxxxx-to-character-in-javascript

Comment: А есть нечто более автоматизированное, мне надо раскодировать, поменять значения и закодировать обратно?

Comment: Vim вполне. Просто читать надо.

      "items": "Аланья\r\n-Центр\r\n-Махмутлар\r\n-Тосмур\r\n-Оба\r\n-Демирташ\r\n-Конаклы\r\n-Турклер\r\n-Джикчилли\r\n-Каргиджак\r\n-Авсаллар\r\n-Кестель\r\n-Клеопатра\r\n-Газипаша\r\nАнталия\r\n-Белек\r\n-Сиде\r\n-Анталия\r\n-Кемер\r\n-Коньялты\r\n-Кунду\r\n-Хурма\r\nКаш\r\nФетхие\r\nБодрум\r\n-Бодрум\r\n-Ялыкавак\r\n-Тюркбюкю\r\n-Гюндоан\r\n-Гюлюк\r\n",
"type": "jbselectcascade"
},

после команды

     :s/\\u\(\x\x\x\x\)/\=nr2char("0x".submatch(1))/g

Comment: @alexlz: есть автоматически, то наверное grep?